# character encoding in a html page

Tags: html, cordova, character-encoding, hybrid-mobile-app

I have 2 html pages `(index.html and game.html)` where I specify the same character encoding UTF-8

in the first page (index.html) every thing works fine but in the second page all characters appear like this �

this is the code of 2 pages :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


        <title>  أصوات</title>
    </head>
    <body dir="rtl" lang='ar' class="contentBack">

    </body>
</html>
```

the result in my browser: 
[image: result]

how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the file is also saved with the corresponding encoding (in your case UTF8). Setting the right meta charset may not be enough.

Comment: thanks Notepad++ save my file with ANSI character encoding